# Difference between ddMMyy and ddmmyy date formats

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I would like to know the difference between `ddMMyy` and `ddmmyy` date formats in C#.

When I try to convert an array of byte into date, same bytes generate different dates for these two formats.

```
byte[] bb = { 0x30, 0x34, 0x30, 0x32, 0x31, 0x35 };
DateTime ddmm = DateTime.ParseExact(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb), "ddmmyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime ddmm1 = DateTime.ParseExact(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb), "ddMMyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`ddmm` variable has '4 Jan 2015' while `ddmm1` has '4 Feb 2015'. Strange!!

Comment: Look through here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx `mm` == `minutes` and `MM` == `Months`

Comment: This must be the first thing you read in the docs, which you read before you use format strings, of course.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite simple actually.

- `mm` stands for minutes;
- `MM` stands for months.

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN for the specifications.

Answer (score 2):

[`mm` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#mmSpecifier) is for minutes. [`MM` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MM_Specifier) is for months.

Since your

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb)
```

returns `040215` as a `string`, if you parse with `ddmmyy` format, your day part will be parse as `4`, your minutes part will be parse as `2` and your year part will be parse as `2015` since you use [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it's current calender's [`Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax.aspx) is `2029` by default.

Other parts of your `DateTime` will be their default values. That's why your `ddmm` will be;

```
04/01/2015 00:02:00 // 4 Jan 2015 2 AM.
```

But if you parse with `ddMMyy` format, your day part will be parse as `4`, your month part will be parsed as `2` and your year part will be parsed as `2015` and the other parts *still* of your `DateTime` will be their default values.

That's why your `ddmm1` will be;

```
04/02/2015 00:00:00 // 4 Feb 2015 midnight
```

Comment: If both ways minutes part will be parse as 2, then why Jan in 1st case and Feb in other.

Comment: @user2861226 No. Please re-read my answer. When you use `ddmmyy` format, your **minutes** part will be parsed as `2`, but when you use `ddMMyy` format, your **month** part will be parsed as `2`. In both cases, all other not formatted parts will be assigned their _default_ values. That's why when you use `ddmmyy`, your `DateTime` will be `04/01/2015 00:02:00` since you specified only day, minutes and year parts on your format, other parts of your `DateTime` (month, hours and seconds) will be assigned their default values which are `1`, `0` and `0` in order. This is the same as for other case.

Answer (score 0):

Date formats are case sensitive.

**MM** produces the two digit month number while **mm** produces the two digit number of minutes.explained over [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=VS.71).aspx).